# Fade images in and out based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to recreate the same effect used here: http://www.chylak.com/en/bags where the images will fade in/out based on scroll position.

I've had a look at the source and can see that "data-centre-centre" and "data-top-bottom" both have opacity values so it looks like a CSS transition?

Thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: What have you tried? Post some of your effort to solve your problem to avoid a closed question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: I've tried using LazyLoad but that's not really the effect I'm after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I ended up using skrollr.js https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Super easy to use and works great if you're trying to achieve a similar effect to the one referenced in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

here you are a little example in this [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamed_badr/31La45p5/)

Comment: Thanks Mohammed, but I'm not really sure how this would work for sequential images? Any ideas?